# NodeJS - Read HTML Head Tags

Tags: html, node.js, web-scraping, domparser

I want to scrape a HTML page in my nodejs application and form a list of head tags. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="script.src"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Desired Output:

```
['<meta charset="UTF-8">','<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">','<title>Document</title>', ...etc]
```

But I am a little stuck as the meta tags do not "close" so it needs more than simple regex and split. I wanted to use `DOMParser` but I am in the node environment. I tried to the `xmldom` npm package but it just returned a list of new line characters (`\r\n`).

Comment: Do you *need* the output to be exactly in that format, or are you just trying to get a logical collection of the tags that can be manipulated somehow?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah it does not *need* to be in that format. But I would like to iterate over it and be able to read the tag name as well as its attributes. I only need it to read, not manipulate the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use Cheerio to parse the HTML and extract the information you need from each element:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const htmlStr = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="script.src"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>`;
const $ = cheerio.load(htmlStr);
const headTags = [];
$('head > *').each((_, elm) => {
  headTags.push({ name: elm.name, attribs: elm.attribs, text: $(elm).text() });
});
console.log(headTags);
```

Output:

```
[ { name: 'meta', attribs: { charset: 'UTF-8' }, text: '' },
  { name: 'meta',
    attribs:
     { name: 'viewport',
       content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' },
    text: '' },
  { name: 'title', attribs: {}, text: 'Document' },
  { name: 'link',
    attribs: { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'style.css' },
    text: '' },
  { name: 'link',
    attribs:
     { rel: 'shortcut icon',
       href: 'favicon.ico',
       type: 'image/x-icon' },
    text: '' },
  { name: 'script', attribs: { src: 'script.src' }, text: '' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

use [request npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to request your page and then after you get response , use [cheerio npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to parse and get whatever you want from raw data .

Note : cheerio has syntax like jQuery

```
 var request = require('request');
 var cheerio = require('cheerio')

app.get('/scrape',(req,res)=>{

request('---your website url to scrape here ---', function (error, response, body) {    
       var $ = cheerio.load(body.toString())
       let headContents=$('head').children().toString();
       console.log('headContents',headContents)
  });

});
```